# Pushing max hash key-values into an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, maxby

I have a hash called `count`, defined as `count = {4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>3, 7=>1}`.

I want to take the `max` value, and then push the key that corresponds to that value into an array, so I do this:

```
array = []
array.push(count.max_by{|k,v| v}[0])

=>> [5]
```

However, `6` also has the value `3`, which is another maximum value. How do I push this value into the array so I get `[5,6]` instead of just `[5]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to choose the `max` values of the hash:

```
count.values.max
=> 3
```

Use the `select` method on the hash:

```
count.select{ |k, v| v == count.values.max }
 => {5=>3, 6=>3}
```

Get the keys:

```
count.select{ |k, v| v == count.values.max }.keys
 => [5, 6]
```

And finally assign to an array:

```
array = count.select{ |k, v| v == count.values.max }.keys
```

Comment: Thank you! great step by step explanation. very helpful in understanding

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be improved dramatically, but off the top of my head:

```
count.group_by{|k,v| v}.max_by{|k,v| k}.last.map(&:first)
```

First, group the key/value pairs of the hash so that the ones with the same value are in the same groups:

```
count.group_by{|k,v| v} #=> {2=>[[4, 2]], 3=>[[5, 3], [6, 3]], 1=>[[7, 1]]}
```

Then get the group with the maximum value:

```
 .max_by{|k,v| k} #=> [3, [[5, 3], [6, 3]]]
```

Now, we just want the original keys out of that, so first we take the last element of the pair:

```
  .last #=> [[5, 3], [6, 3]]
```

And we want just the first element of each of those nested pairs:

```
  .map(&:first) #=> [5, 6]
```

This approach avoids one pass through the map as compared to the `select`-based solutions. It's probably not a significant performance win unless the data set is really huge, in which case the intermediate data structures being built by my solution will be more of a problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
max = count.values.max
array = count.keys.select{|k| count[k] == max}
```